# Laravel behind proxy with nginx maintain https in url using real_ip_header

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using Cloudflare load balancer, our app built with Laravel, the configuration SSL in Cloudflare is "Flexible", SSL managed by cloudflare, from load balancer to our server using HTTP, in Laravel I register the Cloudflare's IP in TrustProxy middleware so the url() and other helper functions can generate HTTPS rather than HTTP, then I enable in nginx `set_real_ip_from` and `real_ip_header` to make our app detect the original client IP, but the url() / TrustProxy not working anymore, it generates HTTP rather than HTTPS, make our assets such as js, css, images is not loaded properly. is there something wrong with my settings?

nginx-cloudflare.conf

```
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 104.24.0.0/14;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

TrustProxies.php

```
<?php
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    protected $proxies = [
        '173.245.48.0/20',
        '103.21.244.0/22',
        '103.22.200.0/22',
        '103.31.4.0/22',
        '141.101.64.0/18',
        '108.162.192.0/18',
        '190.93.240.0/20',
        '188.114.96.0/20',
        '197.234.240.0/22',
        '198.41.128.0/17',
        '162.158.0.0/15',
        '104.16.0.0/13',
        '104.24.0.0/14',
        '172.64.0.0/13',
        '131.0.72.0/22',
        '103.175.217.223', // if user IP is registered here, then it works
    ];

    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

the `url('manage/user')` return `http://example.com/manage/user` rather than `https://example...`, also `HTML::style('css/style.css')` return with http not https, even in .env we already set `APP_URL=https://example.com`